# How to completely remove leftovers of uninstalled software

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I installed a piece of software a long time ago and have kept it up to date. Unfortunately, some of the features have recently been lost after an update.

I attempted to uninstall it from my system and am now trying to install an older version again but it keeps saying that you cannot install an older version. I have checked `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`->`SOFTWARE` in the registry, but I can't find an entry for that software.

Can anyone tell me the reason that this may have happened and how to overcome it?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what the software is that you are having trouble with. This is because keys written to the registry are usually specific to the software that you're using, so the answer to this question will be based on that.

Comment: `YTD Video Downloader`

Comment: @DCoder - Update your question.  Without more specific information, how you remove all traces of this application, cannot be provided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove residual traces of uninstalled software from the registry?](http://superuser.com/questions/180113/how-do-i-remove-residual-traces-of-uninstalled-software-from-the-registry)

Comment: what else information I should provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). Revo Uninstaller has many features to scrub the "remains" of left over trash from installed programs including registry entries. Care should always be given to using these types of tools.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @rrirower please go ahead and edit that into your actual answer.

Comment: Revo Uninstaller did the job very well...

Answer (score 0):

Another great option is [CCleaner](http://download.cnet.com/CCleaner/).  It will remove the garbage and also has a great registry cleaner.  Best of all it's free and well maintained.  The developers are constantly pushing out new editions with many enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

This question is currentlyapproaching 10 years of age. If you come here looking for cleaning for Windows 10/11 (even though the question is for Windows 7), consider trying [Bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/). CCleaner has become bloated and less trustworthy, and if you want to do a one time clean, Revo is relatively expensive.

Bleachbit is lightweight and opensource with plugins for several programs as well, so that each program's history can be wiped as well.